# ExtJS6: How to prevent grid rows from scrolling into focus when clicking

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a grid with a checkbox selection model and tall cells due to custom html renderers. The problem is when any cell is clicked the grid jerks because the selected cell is scrolled into the focus.

Here is a fiddle with the problem, try scrolling the table manually halfway first and then clicking on the cells to see the grid jumping (it's not consistent, might need to try a few times): https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vma

Is there a way to disable row focusing on click, or disable row selection on click if thats the root cause (so you would have to use checkboxes to select rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your grid row contains text that needs to be editable/selectable you can use:

```
viewConfig: {
    navigationModel: {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like it would be a better solution. Are you aware of any downsides of having empty `navigationModel`? Can't find this property mentioned in the docs.

Comment: The nav model was added for ARIA compliance and listens for certain key events (like the up and down arrow), and moves the focus to the currently selected item by adding a 'focusCls' property. It's also listening to click events, which is why the grid is jumping when you click on your cells. It's defined on Ext.view.Table, which Ext.grid.panel extends from. Making it blank will disable navigation by key events like the up and down arrow. Here are the docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.view.NavigationModel.html – Kevin Lee 10 mins ago

Answer (score 2):

I have found that returning false from the "[beforecellmousedown](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.panel.Table.html#event-beforecellmousedown)" event listener function prevents the behavior you are trying to avoid.

```
listeners: {
    beforecellmousedown: function () {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vq3

Answer (score -1):

Suggested earlier answers work for Modern Toolkit only.
For Classic this code helps:

```
listeners: {
    cellclick: function () {
        this.blur();
    }
}
```

Comment: The original question was about Classic and the solution for classic, also, solution from @scebotari66 for Classic.